# OTG + simultaneous charging with USB Type-C cable?

Tags: charging, android, usb-c

This video shows how to make it with a Micro USB. Is it possible to make the same thing with USB Type-C ? My phone has OTG host function. Thanks!

http://youtube.com/watch?v=pH895umr0UA&t=8m43s

Answer (score -1):

the OTG function seems defines in USB2.x 
if your phone has a micro USB receptacle with OTG function even if you use a TYPE-C plug ，the OTG function can works well by using a type-C to micro USB  adapter.

see this：
[image]

if your phone receptacle is type-C ，it seems doesn't have a so called OTG function. In USB2.x the ID pin is used for OTG ，but in USB3.x it doesn't have the ID pin ，for instead ,the CC pin works when it change roles as host or slave.

Comment: Hi, When you copy information from elsewhere into an answer or question, the site rules require that you must [correctly reference it](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Please follow the steps listed on that page and edit your answer to provide the reference information for that image in your answer. Thanks :-)

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is totally confuse me. I don't get it. I have Xiaomi Mi A1 phone which has USB-C port and the app called "USB OTG Checker" says the phone is OK. Is it possible to make the same cable (from video above) with USB-C?